# Firebase: An unexpected error has occurred? Basic setup not working

Tags: html, node.js, firebase, web, firebase-hosting

Ok, I don't know what I could have done wrong here but I am getting the following error just trying to setup the most basic possible Firebase web app -

[image]

What I have done is I created a folder in my home folder with index.html and some styles, basic HTML/CSS stuff. I then cd to that folder in terminal (I followed https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#4 ) and after installing Firebase tools, I did

firebase init

then after I logged in, selected the database from my console hit enter, I tried firebase serve

Then I got that error. I can't find why this might happen. What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you run `firebase serve --debug` and see if that gives you a more useful error message?

Answer (score 3):

copy this and paste it in  `firebase.json` file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "database-rules.json",
      "storage.rules",
      "functions"
    ],
    "headers": [{
      "source" : "**/*.@(js|html)",
      "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Cache-Control",
        "value" : "max-age=0"
      } ]
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was this https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web/issues/29

Have to have right firebase.json